# What is the correct way to extend a parent class method in Python 2.x

Tags: inheritance, python-2.x

I frequently do this sort of thing:

```
class Person(object):
    def greet(self):
        print "Hello"

class Waiter(Person):
    def greet(self):
        Person.greet(self)
        print "Would you like fries with that?"
```

The line Person.greet(self) doesn't seem right. If I ever change what class Waiter inherits from I'm going to have to track down every one of these and replace them all.

What is the correct way to do this is modern Python? Both 2.x and 3.x, I understand there were changes in this area in 3.

If it matters any I generally stick to single inheritance, but if extra stuff is required to accommodate multiple inheritance correctly it would be good to know about that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super):

> Return a proxy object that delegates
>   method calls to a parent or sibling
>   class of type. This is useful for
>   accessing inherited methods that have
>   been overridden in a class. The search
>   order is same as that used by
>   `getattr()` except that the type itself
>   is skipped.

In other words, a call to `super` returns a fake object which delegates attribute lookups to classes above you in the inheritance chain. Points to note:

- This does not work with old-style classes -- so if you are using Python 2.x, you need to ensure that the top class in your hierarchy inherits from `object`.
- You need to pass your own class and instance to `super` in Python 2.x. This requirement was waived in 3.x.
- This will handle all multiple inheritance correctly. (When you have a multiple inheritance tree in Python, a [method resolution order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) is generated and the lookups go through parent classes in this order.)

Take care: there are many places to get confused about multiple inheritance in Python. You might want to read [`super()` Considered Harmful](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/). If you are sure that you are going to stick to a single inheritance tree, and that you are not going to change the names of classes in said tree, you can hardcode the class names as you do above and everything will work fine.

Comment: Here's a documentation link for the 3.x version of [super()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: Just for the record, when referring to `Waiter` in the `super()` function, don't use the class name, but `self.__class__`. This way you won't have to rewrite all your super's in case you change your class name in the future. Like this (inside `Waiter.greet()`): `super(self.__class__, self).greet()`.

Comment: I'd note that often the base implementation of a method won't call super. So it's important in multiple inheritance that the base classes for the methods you are overriding are further right in the MRO than any other overrides of those methods. This is the root of the rule about mixins being listed before bases. This condition is trivially guaranteed if there is only one base class and it's reachable by following the right most parent at every level of the inheritance tree. For example if you are overriding a Django class following the right most parents should always lead to the Django class.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if you're looking for this but you can call a parent without referring to it by doing this.

```
super(Waiter, self).greet()
```

This will call the `greet()` function in `Person`.

Comment: Just for the record, you can also use `super(self.__class__, self).greet()`. This way, in case you change the name of Waiter, you don't have to rewrite your super's.

Comment: @RenatoByrro thanks for this one. This comment should be the answer.

Comment: Don't follow @RenatoByrro's suggestion. If you could determine the correct class by looking at `self`, then `super()` wouldn't take a separate parameter for it, it would just get it from `self`. The class argument is supposed to indicate where in `self.__class__.__mro__` `super` should start looking for the next implementation to call. `self.__class__` is always the **first** entry in the MRO. So if you use this technique anywhere else in the hierarchy you'll just cause infinite recursion.

Comment: @Ben that's probably one more reason why multiple inheritance should be avoided in the first place... You don't have to increase coupling, hard code class names and can forget about the potential MRO issue you pointed out...

Comment: @RenatoByrro Nothing to do with multiple inheritance. `super(self.__class__, self)` will fail even in single inheritance if you use it anywhere other than the leaf class. It's just not a correct way to use `super`.

Comment: The purpose here is to use in the child class, isn't it? I really don't get what is the issue you're pointing... You mentioned MRO and first place in the inheritance hierarchy, suggesting a problem involving multiple inheritance. I don't get why your suggestion had nothing to do with multiple inheritance...

Comment: @RenatoByrro If you have `class Base(object)`, `class  A(Base)`, and `class B(A)`, then your suggestion will only work in class `B` (and only if no one ever adds a subclass of `B`). But none of these classes has multiple parents, so the problem doesn't only manifest in multiple inheritance. Single inheritance hierarchies still have an MRO, even if it's just the obvious sequence from leaf class to `object`.

Answer (score 5):

katrielalex's answer is really the answer to your question, but this wouldn't fit in a comment.

If you plan to go about using `super` everywhere, and you ever think in terms of multiple inheritance, definitely read the "super() Considered Harmful" link. `super()` is a great tool, but it takes understanding to use correctly. In my experience, for simple things that don't seem likely to get into complicated diamond inheritance tangles, it's actually easier and less tedious to just call the superclass directly and deal with the renames when you change the name of the base class.

In fact, in Python2 you have to include the current class name, which is usually more likely to change than the base class name. (And in fact sometimes it's very difficult to pass a reference to the current class if you're doing wacky things; at the point when the method is being defined the class isn't bound to any name, and at the point when the `super` call is executed the original name of the class may not still be bound to the class, such as when you're using a class decorator)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to make it more explicit in this answer with an example. It's just like [how we do in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46244457/3552975). The short answer is, do that like we initiate the constructor using `super`.

```
class Person(object):                                                             
   def __init__(self, name):                                                      
       self.name = name                                                           
                                                                                    
   def greet(self):                                                               
       print(f"Hello, I'm {self.name}")                                           
                                                                                    
class Waiter(Person):                                                             
    def __init__(self, name):                                                     
        super().__init__(name)
        # initiate the parent constructor
        # or super(Waiter, self).__init__(name)                                                    
                                                                                    
    def greet(self):                                                              
        super(Waiter, self).greet()                                               
        print("Would you like fries with that?")                                  
                                                                                    
waiter = Waiter("John")                                                           
waiter.greet()

# Hello, I'm John
# Would you like fries with that?
```