# Django Static Files: Any Way to Get More Fine-Grained Control?

Tags: django

Django's static files feature allows you to specify certain directories to have "collected" in to a public-facing folder.  That's great, but is there any way to get more fine-grained control than just having certain folders?  For instance, is there anyway to specify ...

- Including specific files
- Excluding specific files
- Excluding specific sub-directories

For instance, I'd like to say "collect all the files in this one folder except for this one file and this one directory".  Alternatively, I could accomplish the same thing if I could pick specific files, and then pick all of the sub-directories of that one directory (except the one I don't want).

Is any of that possible?

Comment: Some examples are at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269883/how-to-ignore-directories-when-running-django-collectstatic

Comment: Thanks, that would work.  However, our ops guy would prefer to avoid command line flags, so ideally I was looking for a way to do this with settings, class-overrides ... something like that.

Comment: How about writing a custom management command that sets the flags and calls the original? You can still call it collectstatic.

Comment: ... or you could write a custom static-file finder that has the properties you want. That will be more flexible. I've never done that but it doesn't look too hard.

Comment: If you need some help with it, I can try to help you with it. Seems like an interesting problem. Also seems like django should improve this -- it's currently hardwired to file patterns CVS, *~, .* by default.

Comment: Good idea! `COLLECT_STATIC_EXCLUDE` and `COLLECT_STATIC_INCLUDE` settings! :).

Comment: It needs to be said, why are you putting files in the static file folders that aren't going to be collected? This sounds like a problem elsewhere.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid because the static folders are a convenient place to have some development files and those files don't need to go public. I think sass files are the best example.

Comment: If you have sass files, then you need to store them outside of static files and only the generated files should be stored in static files. I think having a static file "filtering" is just going to encourage bad habits; people start using the static folders for all kinds of files.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I agree that bad habits are bad and we shouldn't encourage them. Two points: 1) The collectstatic command has an `--ignore` flag. So the functionality is there. 2) 'All kinds of files' are in Django itself. Take the static files that come with the admin. It contains `actions.js` and a generated `actions.min.js`. One is for development the other production. Both get collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a custom django-admin command to enable a `COLLECT_STATIC_IGNORE` setting.

First create the following stucture in any app folder:

```
appname/
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            _private.py
            collectstatic.py
```

In collectstatic.py put:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.collectstatic import Command
from django.conf import settings

class Command(Command):

    def set_options(self, **options):
        """
        Set instance variables based on an options dict
        """
        self.interactive = options['interactive']
        self.verbosity = int(options.get('verbosity', 1))
        self.symlink = options['link']
        self.clear = options['clear']
        self.dry_run = options['dry_run']
        ignore_patterns = options['ignore_patterns']
        if options['use_default_ignore_patterns']:
            ignore_patterns += ['CVS', '.*', '*~']
            ignore_patterns += settings.COLLECT_STATIC_IGNORE # Added.
        self.ignore_patterns = list(set(ignore_patterns))
        self.post_process = options['post_process']
```

Or, even better, as suggested, use [super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070599/what-is-the-correct-way-to-extend-a-parent-class-method-in-modern-python#answer-6070685):

```
class Command(Command):

    def set_options(self, **options):
        super(Command, self).set_options(**options)
        self.ignore_patterns += settings.COLLECT_STATIC_IGNORE        
        self.ignore_patterns = list(set(self.ignore_patterns))
```

This overrides the `set_options` function from de build-in `collectstatic` command.

In settings.py add `COLLECT_STATIC_IGNORE`.
This example ignores scss files and all files in admin folders.

```
COLLECT_STATIC_IGNORE = ['*.scss', 'admin', ... ]
```

Then:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Flags work so after adding something to `COLLECT_STATIC_IGNORE` you might want to use `--clear` to clear the existing files before trying to copy or link the original file.

```
python manage.py collectstatic --clear
```

Comment: This is my first django-admin command so feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Nicely done! One suggestion -- call the ancestor's set_options, then do your custom stuff (setting ignore_patterns). e.g.  `super(Command, self).set_options(**options)` .  That way you don't have to repeat the base functionality, and you get new functionality in future versions automatically. You might need to change your Command class name b/c you're overwriting the ancestor's name.

Comment: @CantucciHQ: I don't know enough about super to feel confident. Can you have a look at it? Not renaming seems to work fine. Thanks for the tip.